# Вывод мусора в консоль вместо текста?

Tags: кодировка, консоль, freepascal

Почему если выводить строку через `writeln`, то она будет представляться в качестве каких-то непонятных символов?

```
program test;

procedure palindrom(str: string);
  var
    s1, s2: string;
    i: integer;
  begin
    for i := 1 to length(str) do
      if str[i] <> ' ' then
        s1 := concat(s1, str[i]);

    i := length(s1);

    while i > 0 do
      begin
        s2 := concat(s2, s1[i]);

        i := i - 1;
      end;

    writeln(s1, s2);

    if s1 = s2 then writeln(1)
    else writeln(0);
  end;

begin
  palindrom('a mene nema');
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не кодировка, а просто какой-то мусор выводится ..

Comment: @Kromster почему так происходит? у меня проблема не только с этой программой, а и с другой тоже. никакой мусор в строку не добавляю..

Comment: В отладчике проверяли, в s1 и s2 во время работы правильный текст?

Comment: @Kromster str[i] выводит нормально, а вот в s1 выводит мусор

Comment: Перечитайте мой вопрос, он достаточно конкретен.

Comment: У вас не задана s1 и  s2 явно. Не все компиляторы инициализируют переменные (ну ещё нужно опции проверять). Задайте их явно. По умолчанию там может быть мусор:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что в s1 и s2 изначально содержится мусор. При объявлении переменной типа "строка" в памяти резервируется 255 байт (или сколько там необходимо для хранения строки), но при этом не обнуляется и в ней хранится что то, что ранее было в оперативке по этому адресу.

По этому переменные нужно инициализировать:

```
procedure palindrom(str: string);
  var
    s1, s2: string;
    i: integer;
begin
    s1:='';
    s2:='';
    i:=0;
...
```

тогда можно быть уверенным, что s1, s2 - пустая строка, а i = 0

Answer (score 0):

Если подобная проблема обнаружится при выводе инициализированной строки, то обычно это лечится:

```
uses crt;
```